# Property-Trait with "depends_on"

Tags: python, enthought, traits

Given traits-based classes Material-class, Base-class and Child-class (derived from the Base-class), the following code runs if the Property-trait `b` of the Child-class depends_on only `a` or `x` attributes, i.e.

`b = Property(Float, depends_on=['a'])`

or

`b = Property(Float, depends_on=['x'])`

but not if it depends on both:

`b = Property(Float, depends_on=['a','x'])`

Why?

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, DelegatesTo, Float, Instance, Range, Property

class Material(HasTraits):
    a = Float(10)

class Base(HasTraits):
    x = Float(-1)

class Child(Base):
    m = Instance(Material)
    a = DelegatesTo('m')
    # b = Property(Float, depends_on=['a'])     # <-- runs
    # b = Property(Float, depends_on=['x'])     # <-- runs
    b = Property(Float, depends_on=['a','x'])   # <-- fails

    def _get_b(self):
        return self.a * self.x

c = Child(m=Material())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve that by not using a `DelegatesTo` and only listen to changes on `m.a`:

```
class Child(Base):
    m = Instance(Material)
    b = Property(Float, depends_on=['m.a','x'])   # <-- runs

    def _get_b(self):
        return self.a * self.x
```

The issue with the delegate seems related to set up the listener. The error message I get is

`DelegationError: The 'a' attribute of a 'Child' object has a delegate which does not have traits.`.